# Javascript formData array returns empty

Tags: javascript, php

I have an issue with my AJAX formData object. If select a file in the input and I send this with AJAX the array is empty. I hope somebody can help me with this. Below my code

HTML and JavaScript

```
    <form method="post" id="quoteform">
        <input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="quote"/>
        <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("quoteform").addEventListener("submit", function(){
        var files           = document.getElementById("quote").files;
        var formData        = new FormData();
        
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i]
            formData.append('files[]', file);
        }


        var xhttp           = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "linktophpfile.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send('upload='+formData);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
```

The PHP file returns
**Array
(
)**

Comment: when youre dealing with files it should be `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. when you upload files then you can't use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you have to use `multipart/form-data`
2. you shouldn't mix strings with formData `send('upload='+formData)` it will only result in you uploading a string equal to `upload=[Object object]`

you should instead just send the formData and let the XHR or Fetch handle the content-type for you automatically.

3. If you want an array then i presume you also want the attribute `mulitple`? You could always add in the `required` and `accept="image/*, .txt"` for good measure
4. You don't manually have to add in all files to a formdata if you just use the first constructor argument that accepts a form element, everything from the form will be added

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://httpbin.org/post" id="quoteform" encoding="multipart/form-data">
  <input multiple type="file" name="files[]" id="quote" required />
  <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
<script>
// html (xml) should mark the settings, behavior as it mostly always have done
// in all years way back and the js should provide enhancement and
// be more generally written to enhance the site (if js where
// to be turned off - most unlikely, I for once have it disabled in my phone)
// static sites works better without ads + annoying cookie popups
// it's a good thing Brave have quick toggle to enable scrips for js-only pages

function ajaxify (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  var form = evt.target
  var formData = new FormData(form)

  fetch(form.action, {
    method: form.method,
    body: formData
  }).then(res => res.text()).then(alert)
}

document.getElementById("quoteform").addEventListener("submit", ajaxify)
</script>
```